# How to add admin_menu for regular users on wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a custom submenu on my wordpress plugin using below code, but this is only available for admins how can i add a sub menu for regular users?

`add_action('admin_menu')`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i manage to display it by changing the capability from `manage_options` to `read` referensing on this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities